# Applying tuple operations element-wise to a numpy array of tuples

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with a 2d array of "pixels" (rgb int tuples), and I need an efficient way to apply some numpy operations to each element. Specifically, I'm trying to find pixels within a few color shades of a goal colour to later isolate them with numpy.nonzero

Using For loops is for this case takes tens of seconds, so I'm looking to apply the numpy operations element-wise to achieve the same result.

I'm looking to apply

Tuple subtraction :

```
pixel_diff = numpy.subtract( pixel_a, pixel_b)
```

Tuple absolute value:

```
pixel_abs = numpy.abs( pixel_diff )
```

Tuple comparison:

```
pixel_bool = pixel_abs < int_tolerance
```

Tuple all ():

```
is_similar = numpy.all(pixel_bool)
```

Trying to apply any of these operations blindly to my array results in invalid promotion errors, so I figure there must be a proper way to do it, instead.

Comment: Why do you keep referencing tuples? If you're passing tuples to numpy methods, they are being converted to arrays before any work can actually take place.

Comment: how exactly does your `pixels` array look like?

Comment: The array (on my machine) is 2d of shape `(1920, 1080)` with dtype `[('x0', int), ('x1', int), ('x2', int)]`. I've only heard of this format being referred to as 'an array of tuples' thus far. - if a 3d array would be more helpful for me, i can easily reshape.

Comment: Mmm, that looks more like a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) and it's not clear to me why the library would return such an object, rather than a 2D array of a single type. What library is this?

Comment: You can convert to equivalent views to avoid the errors. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   import numpy as np
   #create a RGB array of 1000x1000x3 and separate into colors
   R, G, B = np.random.randint(0, 255, size = (1000, 1000, 3))
   #find all pixels less than 100, 100, 100
   np.logical_and((R<100), (G<100), (B<100))
```

You may modify the last line to suit your color needs.  As is, the last line takes about 1.5 ms on a single core.

Comment: Seems like a solid solution - To be clear though, this is applying the operation by restructuring the array into 3 2d arrays of ints? (I'll have to reshape and split to test for my use case)

Comment: Yes, in order to get the most out of numpy vectorization, you should restructure your problem in a way that allows for in-place array operations, which are much faster than going element by element.

Comment: @Mike: **(a)** The assignment line throws an error. It would work only if the rhs had a shape of `(3,1000,1000)`. **(b)** Referring to your comment above, "element-by-element" doesn't mean it can't be "in-place"

Comment: @fountainhead a) the code above worked for me.  you may be seeing an issue with the convention of defining rgb images.  b) that's true, that was careless phrasing on my part.

Comment: @Mike: I tried again, and I get the error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)". `R, G, B = np.random.randint(0, 255, size = (1000, 1000, 3))`. That line just uses the `randint()` function, which doesn't care about rgb conventions. It's trying to create an array of `1000x1000x3`, which is equivalent to a `1000` sub-arrays each of size `1000x3` and unpack it into `3` variables. The mismatch is between `1000` and `3`. It just won't work.

Comment: Hard to tell what your issue is.  The following should work just as well:

```R = np.random.randint(0, 255, size = (1000, 1000)); G = np.random.randint(0, 255, size = (1000, 1000)); B = np.random.randint(0, 255, size = (1000, 1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert into an **equivalent non-structured view** (without incurring any additional cost of making a copy of the underlying data):

```
my_3dview_of_ints = my_2d_of_3tuples.view(dtype=int)
```

where `my_2d_of_3tuples` is your current structured array (array of tuples)

You can then perform your usual numpy array operations on this view without running into any type errors.

For example, if your array looks like this:

```
 [[(207,  27, 185) ( 90, 197,  52) ( 58, 153, 145) (239,  42,  39)]
 [(218,  23, 195) (226,  92, 170) ( 21, 114, 190) (192, 145,  48)]]
```

then the view, as created above, would look like this:

```
[[[207  27 185]
  [ 90 197  52]
  [ 58 153 145]
  [239  42  39]]

 [[218  23 195]
  [226  92 170]
  [ 21 114 190]
  [192 145  48]]]
```

For example:

```
pixel_a = my_3dview_of_ints[0,0] # pixel [207,27,185] at [0,0]
pixel_b = my_3dview_of_ints[1,1] # pixel [226,92,170] at [1,1]

pixel_diff = numpy.subtract( pixel_a, pixel_b) # Gives [-12,-65,5]
```

You can even change specific elements in the view, and the changes would automatically reflect at the corresponding location in your original structured array:

```
my_3dview_of_ints[3,3] = pixel_a # Assign [207, 27,185] to location [3,3]
```